# Bounded sequence implies subsequence converges with specific rate?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is probably a very basic or stupid question, but I will ask anyways.

Suppose $(a_n)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded. There there exists a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ with limit $a$. Can we say that $|a_{n_k}-a|\le \frac{1}{n_k}$ for all $k\ge 1$? If not, then what about with $1$ replaced by $C>1$?

My thinking is since $a_n$ is bounded, $|a_{n_k}-a|\le C$ for some constant $C>0$. I think some sort of diagonal argument works, assuming I am not having a brain fart and it is immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong. Check, for example, $a_n = \frac 1{\sqrt n}$. Then $a_n\to 0$ and any subsequence converges to zero. So, $a=0$. Assume that $a_{n_k}\le\frac C{n_k}$. Then
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n_k}}{n_k} = \frac 1{\sqrt{n_k}}\le\frac C{n_k}
$$
and hence $\sqrt{n_k}\le C$ for all $k$, which is impossible!